# Bluetooth Communication between Android/Windows, missing Messages

Tags: android, windows, multithreading, delphi, bluetooth

I am trying to write a small Bluetooth-Protocol for sending B64 encoded messages from an android device to a windows device and vice versa.
For this I am using 3 Threads capsulated in one class.

```
  TBluetooth = class
  private
    FBTReceiveThread: TBTReceiveThread;
    FBTSendThread: TBTSendThread;
    FBTMsgHandlerThread: TBTMsgHandlerThread;
    FBluetoothManager: TBluetoothManager;
    FServiceName: String;
    FServiceGUID: String;
    function ManagerConnected(): Boolean;
  public
    constructor create(const AServicename: STring; const aGuid: String; const AValue: TBluetoothOnMsgReady);
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    function ListPairedDevices: TBluetoothDeviceList;
    function getDeviceFromAdress(const Aadress: String): TBluetoothDevice;
    function sendMessage(const aData: STring; const aIdentifier: STring; const Aadress: String;
      const HighPriority: Boolean): TGuid;
    procedure startListening;
    // procedure stopListening;
    procedure SetBluetoothOnError(const AValue: TBluetoothOnError);
    procedure SetBluetoothOnMSGReady(const AValue: TBluetoothOnMsgReady);
    procedure SetBluetoothSendStatus(const AValue: TBLuetoothSendStatus);
    property BluetoothOnMSGReady: TBluetoothOnMsgReady write SetBluetoothOnMSGReady;
    property BluetoothOnError: TBluetoothOnError write SetBluetoothOnError;
    property BluetoothSendStatus: TBLuetoothSendStatus write SetBluetoothSendStatus;
  end;
```

One is for sending the messages, one is for receiving them and one is for combining the parts of messages.

### SendThread

The message is split manually for more control over when they are sent and to easily combine them on the revieving end.
I am adding the message parts to a queue and the "sendthread" is sending them one by one.

```
procedure TBTSendThread.Execute;
var
  msgToSend: TBtMsgRec;
  msgHeader, statusstr: String;
  fData: TBytes;
begin
  inherited;
  while not terminated do
    try
      if (FQueue.Count > 0) then
      begin
        TMonitor.Enter(FLock);
        try
          msgToSend := FQueue.First;
          FQueue.Delete(0);
          FSocket := msgToSend.targetDevice.CreateClientSocket(StringToGuid(FServiceGUID), True);
          FSocket.Connect;

          msgHeader := msgToSend.Identifier + '|' + GUIDToString(msgToSend.FGuid) + '|' + inttoStr(msgToSend.Length) +
            '|' + inttoStr(msgToSend.part) + '/' + inttoStr(msgToSend.max) + '|';
          fData := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgHeader + msgToSend.Data);
          FSocket.SendData(fData);
          if (msgToSend.part = msgToSend.max) then
            dec(fQueueCount);
          if assigned(FGetSendStatus) then
            Synchronize(
              procedure
              begin
                FGetSendStatus(msgToSend.FGuid, msgToSend.Length, msgToSend.part, msgToSend.max, fQueueCount);
              end);
          Sleep(50);
        finally
          TMonitor.Exit(FLock);
          FSocket.close;
        end;
      end;
    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        Synchronize(
          procedure
          begin
            if assigned(FBLuetoothOnError) then
              FBLuetoothOnError(e);
          end);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

### Recieve Thread

The recieve thread reads the buffer of the Socket and passes the raw string to the msghandler thread.

```
procedure TBTReceiveThread.Execute;
var
  FSocket: TBluetoothSocket;
  ok: Boolean;
  LData: TBytes;
begin
  inherited;
  while not terminated do
    try
      FSocket := FServerSocket.Accept(500);
      if FSocket <> nil then
      begin
        ok := True;
        while ok do
          try
            LData := FSocket.ReceiveData;
            if (Length(LData) > 0) and assigned(FMsgHandlerThread) then
              FMsgHandlerThread.addRawMsg(TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(LData));
          except
            ok := false;
          end;
        SetLength(LData, 0);
        //sleep(50);
      end;
    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        Synchronize(
          procedure
          begin
            if assigned(FBLuetoothOnError) then
              FBLuetoothOnError(e);
          end);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

### MSGHandler Thread

The MSGHandler Thread takes the raw strings and combines them in to complete messages. When it gets the last part of a message it hands the completed message off.

```
  procedure TBTMsgHandlerThread.Execute();
var
  msg: TBtMsgRec;
  NewMsg: Boolean;
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  while not terminated do
  begin
    if (FRawMsgList.Count > 0) then
    begin
      msg := parseMsg(FRawMsgList.First);
      FRawMsgList.Delete(0);
      NewMsg := True;

      for i := 0 to FParsedMsgList.Count - 1 do
        if (msg.FGuid = FParsedMsgList[i].FGuid) then
        begin
          NewMsg := false;
          msg.Data := FParsedMsgList[i].Data + msg.Data;
          FParsedMsgList.Delete(i);
          if (msg.part = msg.max) then
            Synchronize(
              procedure
              begin
                if assigned(FBluetoothOnMsgReady) then
                  FBluetoothOnMsgReady(msg);
              end)
          else
            FParsedMsgList.add(msg);
          break;
        end;
      if NewMsg then
        if msg.max = 1 then
          Synchronize(
            procedure
            begin
              if assigned(FBluetoothOnMsgReady) then
                FBluetoothOnMsgReady(msg);
            end)
        else
          FParsedMsgList.add(msg);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

### Problem summary:

The sending (monitored with a callback which informs me about the status of the send message) and combining part works fine but some messages are not reaching their target. I am not able to see a pattern and sadly there are no error messages.

I think the problem lies in my usage of threads. My theory is that the reciever thread somehow misses some messages.
So I tried upping the priority of the receiving thread and also changing the sleep time of the threads. Even though i think it is not a good idea to use sleep in threads. But it is my first time working with threads and most code examples for Bluetooth communication use it.

### Edit:

```
procedure TBTMsgHandlerThread.addRawMsg(ARawMsg: String);
begin
  Synchronize(
    procedure
    begin
      FRawMsgList.add(ARawMsg);
    end);
end;
```

Comment: for a question this long it could be a good idea to create a summary of the key points at the end. Whats going wrong. why you think it is going wrong. any key log messages or error messages. It makes it easier for people to summarize the question.

Comment: Making sure FRawMsgList is accessed in a thread safe manner would be one place to start.  You don't show the source for addRawMsg() but the code in the MSGHandler thread  touching FRawMsgList does not look thread safe,

Comment: @Brian Yes that is kind of my problem i am not sure how to handle it properly. I edited the post to include the procedure.